# Django form for each item in a list

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to make a webapp using django that allows the user to choose who they believe the winner will be in a couple of games.  I have the games as a model that has the home team, away team, id, among other things.  Now on submit I would like the users to insert multiple rows into a table that has the user id and the team they have selected.

I have tried using formsets, but I can't figure out how they work with different labels.

The form I currently have is this.

```
class PickForm(forms.ModelForm):
'''
    A form that allows a user to make a pick on the
    selected game
'''
error_messages = {
    'no_match': ('Your selections do not match the corresponding options')
}

team_picked = forms.CharField(label=('Your choice'))

class Meta:
    model = Pick
    fields = ('team_picked',)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id', None)
    self.matchweek = kwargs.pop('matchweek', None)
    super(PickForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_team_picked(self):
    team_picked = self.cleaned_data['team_picked']
    if(team_picked == self.home_team):
        return team_picked
    elif(team_picked == self.away_team):
        return team_picked
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['no_match'],
            code='no_match',
        )

def save(self, commit=True):
    pick = super(PickForm, self).save(commit=False)
    pick.team_picked = self.cleaned_data['team_picked']
    pick.user_id = self.user_id
    pick.matchweek = self.matchweek
    if commit:
        pick.save()
    return pick
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not certain what you mean about the "different labels", but it looks like you want a Model formset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

So you'd have something like

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from models import PickForm

PickFormSet = modelformset_factory(Pick, form=PickForm, queryset=Pick.objects.filter())
```